# Apache Pig ToDate UDF Timestamp format

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I am using ToDate UDF in pig for generating a datetime field.
Input is in yyyy-MM-dd format.
ToDate(sch_trans_dt,'yyyy-MM-dd','Etc/GMT+7') is generating the value with a colon in timestamp field as 
2015-11-26T00:00:00.000-**07:00**
Is there a way to avoid the colon in the timestamp and make the generated value as 2015-11-26T00:00:00.000-**0700**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ref :** http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#to-string

Return type of ToDate function is DateTime object (ISO 8601 format). To convert this to customized string format we can use ToString function by giving 
required format string as the second parameter.

**Pig Script :**

```
A = LOAD 'input.csv' AS (datestring:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToString(ToDate(datestring,'yyyy-MM-dd','Etc/GMT+7'),'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:ss:mm.SZ');
DUMP B;
```

**Input :**

```
2015-11-26
```

**Output :**

```
(2015-11-26T12:00:00.0-0700)
```